# I can't get Scribes recognize my .html.erb files

Tags: syntax-highlighting

That's it. Scribes just doesn't highlight or load templates for my Ruby on Rails templates.

Any of you had better luck?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following instruction and it should be working.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-on-rails/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```